# Rails 5 partial form not showing in production but is in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the relevant code. This all works on my development server with a direct code copy to the production server.  Development works fine.  I don't do much with html or css so it could be there.  Anyone see something obvious?  I've checked suggestions from other similar questions in the forums but I'm not seeing it.
Code from exams controller:

```
  def new
    @exam = Exam.new
    @exam.questions.build if @exam.questions.blank?
  end

  # GET /exams/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /exams
  # POST /exams.json
  def create
      @exam = Exam.new(exam_params)
      respond_to do |format|
      if @exam.save
        format.html { redirect_to @exam, notice: 'Exam was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @exam }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @exam.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

_form

```
<%= form_for(@exam) do |f| %>
  <% if @exam.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(exam.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this exam from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @exam.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>:
    <%= f.text_field :title,:size =>"50" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
       <%= f.check_box :pcredit %>
       <%= f.label :pcredit, "Give partial credit when a question has multiple correct answers." %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :available %>
    <%= f.label :available, "Available to take" %>
  </div>

<% exam.user_id = current_user.id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :department_id, value: current_user.department_id %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :retake %>
      <%= f.label :retake, "Retakes allowed" %>
   </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :results %>
    <%= f.label :results, "Show results" %>
  </div>
  <hr>
   <div id="questions">
      <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
        <%= render 'question_fields', f: question  %>
      <hr>
      <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add_question', f, :questions,  partial: 'question_fields' %>
    </div> 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Questions Partial

```
<strong>Question:</strong>
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Question:" %>
    <%= f.text_area :name,:size =>"50" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value, "Point Value:" %>
    <%= f.number_field :value %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :available %>
    <%= f.check_box :available %>
  </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove question", f %>
     <div>
       <p><strong>Answers:</strong></p>
       <div id="answers">
         <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
           <%= render 'answer_fields', f: answer  %> 
         <% end %>
       </div>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add_answer', f, :answers,  partial: 'answer_fields' %>
        <hr>
     </div>
</div>
```

---

Answers Partial

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Answer:" %>
    <%= f.text_area :name,:size =>"50" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :correct %>
    <%= f.check_box :correct %>
 </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :creator_id, value: current_user.id %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :department_id, value: current_user.department_id %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :locked %>
    <%= f.check_box :locked %><br>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove answer", f %>
 </div>
```

---

Page Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Online Placements</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/exams-72737ac2bb269793edd945e3daa76d03d1bc74588f32b4acceb48ba3328ddc14.css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-3199215ebdb5afca46347c9bb159d59b78620065cea4336725d6fdeebc9e0e12.js"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="+r+/jvc85b8QgSkJrpoT/idGMB3vYnkfLePBCjnWdsGBP1xhb/L86UA80toVa+/SXxGzb1KhDR0mm8hLkGt+Fw==" />
</head>
<body id="exams">



  <div id="banner"> 
    <img src=/assets/KHSlogo-3f9139495681edc2572d84a2d1157e33990d56e4536f98c1addaf5e9c092b2fc.gif width="160" height="77" alt="*****" />
    <title1>**************</title1>
    <p id="notice"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="columns">
    <div id="side">
      <font color="#ff0000">Home</font><br>

      <a href="/examinations">Placements</a>
      <br>
      <hr>

      <font color="#ff0000">Admins Only</font><br>
      <a href="/users">Users</a>
      <br>
      <hr>

      <font color="#ff0000">Documentation</font>

        <br><a target="_blank" href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/11_WLL7wZIkzssubus4XAQcouKkpRdrG6Lu-dWGn7gJY/edit#bookmark=id.8glqcm3gxwmz">User Document</a>
        <br><a target="_blank" href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/11_WLL7wZIkzssubus4XAQcouKkpRdrG6Lu-dWGn7gJY/edit#bookmark=id.o7htlx2i1tyx">Placement Help</a>

    </div>   
   <div id="main">
     <li> 
      Logged in as <b>****- </b>
      <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>   
     </li>
    <h1>Editing Exam: Placement Test</h1>

    <form class="edit_exam" id="edit_exam_1" action="/exams/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="K98vKBkYaUZL5WOt5xjlopkOVk7pvhc3HgBp5M0zmsQu3Hy2oBN5AzZjI3gTYcghP9qhXrpqAQenrZnYcVNw5Q==" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="exam_title">Title</label>:
    <input size="50" type="text" value="Placement Test" name="exam[title]" id="exam_title" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
       <input name="exam[pcredit]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="exam[pcredit]" id="exam_pcredit" />
       <label for="exam_pcredit">Give partial credit when a question has multiple correct answers.</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input name="exam[available]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="exam[available]" id="exam_available" />
    <label for="exam_available">Available to take</label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="exam[user_id]" id="exam_user_id" />
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="exam[department_id]" id="exam_department_id" />
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <input value="1" type="hidden" name="exam[creator_id]" id="exam_creator_id" />
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <input name="exam[retake]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="exam[retake]" id="exam_retake" />
      <label for="exam_retake">Retakes allowed</label>
   </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input name="exam[results]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="exam[results]" id="exam_results" />
    <label for="exam_results">Show results</label>
  </div>
  <hr>

   <div id="questions">

  <a class="add_fields" data-association="question" data-associations="questions" data-association-insertion-template="&lt;strong&gt;Question:&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;div class=&#39;nested-fields&#39;&gt;
  &lt;div class=&quot;field&quot;&gt;
    &lt;label for=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_name&quot;&gt;Question:&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;textarea name=&quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][name]&quot; id=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_name&quot; cols=&quot;50&quot;&gt;
&lt;/textarea&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;

  &lt;div class=&quot;field&quot;&gt;
    &lt;label for=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_value&quot;&gt;Point Value:&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;input type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][value]&quot; id=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_value&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class=&quot;field&quot;&gt;
    &lt;label for=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_available&quot;&gt;Available&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;input name=&quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][available]&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;checkbox&quot; value=&quot;1&quot; name=&quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][available]&quot; id=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_available&quot; /&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions__destroy&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;remove_fields dynamic&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;remove question&lt;/a&gt;
     &lt;div&gt;
       &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Answers:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
       &lt;div id=&quot;answers&quot;&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;a class=&quot;add_fields&quot; data-association=&quot;answer&quot; data-associations=&quot;answers&quot; data-association-insertion-template=&quot;  &amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;field&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;label for=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_name&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Answer:&amp;lt;/label&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;textarea name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][name]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_name&amp;quot; cols=&amp;quot;50&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;/textarea&amp;gt;
  &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
  &amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;field&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;label for=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_correct&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Correct&amp;lt;/label&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;input name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][correct]&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; value=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;input type=&amp;quot;checkbox&amp;quot; value=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][correct]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_correct&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;
 &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
   &amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;field&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;input value=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][creator_id]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_creator_id&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;
 &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;
 &amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;field&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;input value=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][department_id]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_department_id&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;
 &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;

 &amp;lt;div class=&amp;quot;field&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;label for=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_locked&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Locked&amp;lt;/label&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;input name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][locked]&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; value=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;input type=&amp;quot;checkbox&amp;quot; value=&amp;quot;1&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][locked]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers_locked&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;input type=&amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;exam[questions_attributes][new_questions][answers_attributes][new_answers][_destroy]&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;exam_questions_attributes_new_questions_answers_attributes_new_answers__destroy&amp;quot; value=&amp;quot;false&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a class=&amp;quot;remove_fields dynamic&amp;quot; href=&amp;quot;#&amp;quot;&amp;gt;remove answer&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;
 &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt; 
    &quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;add_answer&lt;/a&gt;
        &lt;hr&gt;
     &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;    
" href="#">add_question</a>
    </div> 
  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Exam" data-disable-with="Update Exam" />
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/exams/1">Show</a> |
<a href="/exams">Back</a>
<br><br><br>

   </div>

 </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not really explaining what you are expecting to see. But without controller code and database model, this looks perfectly fine to me. You have to add a question before you can see them, and only then can you add answers, right? Development looks fine because there already is data available?

Comment: What I'm expecting to see as I explained is the questions partial which of course takes as input the question fields.  I get nothing.  In development with an empty database creating the first exam with questions works perfectly.  In the log I see that the partial is rendered but nothing shows.  That's why I suspect something in html/css.

Comment: Sorry the problem occurs when I try to add a new question.  I guess that wasn't clear in my initial post.

Comment: Also if it isn't clear I'm following an example of using the cocoon gem hence the link_to_add_association in the _form...

Comment: Title:  (String value followed by 4 check boxes)
 Checkbox:Give partial credit when a question has multiple correct answers.
Checkbox: Available to take
Checkbox: Retakes allowed
Checkbox:Show results                                                                      Link:  add_question  (This link should create a new question using cocoon and bring up the partial)
Link:  Back

Comment: So expected behaviour is you click on the "Add question" link and form appears, but nothing happens?
Did you check console for javascript errors?
Did you add "//= require cocoon"?

Comment: To continue: I'm following an example using the cocoon gem which creates associations.  In the _form for Exam there is a link to add a question: link_to_add_association (cocoon). when the link is clicked a new question is generated and the partial should appear with the question fields.  In the log the partials get rendered but nothing happens on the screen.  Again this all works on the development server, same RVM versions of rails, ruby and it's using the same Gemfile.

Comment: re: Alexander: When I click on add question link nothing appears. 
 Nothing in the java console, require cocoon is there.  Same files as the working development...  Maybe some version difference in the servers.  I'll look again deeper. cocoon 1.2.11
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.Using rails 5.0.7 Ruby 2.3.3p222

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see controller part for it where `@exam` is defined
I assume that in your prod case (where form doesn't show) association `questions` is empty.
So there are several variants:

1.In controller always build a question if the association is empty

`@exam.questions.build if @exam.questions.blank?`

2.You can add entity in the view

```
f.fields_for :questions, @exam.questions.presence || [@exam.questions.build] do |question|
```

3.Take into account such case in view and show proper message

```
<% if @exam.questions.present? %>
  <%= render 'questions_part' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'no_questions_partial' %>
<% end %>
```

I think 1 variant is better.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.  I tried 1. which pre-built a question when I added a new exam but still the questions partial doesn't show.  I also added a pre-build for answers but still nothing.  Re-started the app and the web server.  I added relevant controller code above.

Comment: With this controller code please try

`f.fields_for :questions, @exam.questions`

I think it should work this way

Comment: Alexander;  Tried it but got this response: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR,  I think my original syntax is correct there. It must be something environmental as in server setup, or something that development mode ignores but causes production to soft reject. I don;t get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally figured it out. I had to precompile assets.  Working now.
Thanks to those who offered suggestions.  I really appreciate your time.